# res.json() is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongoose, next.js

*** on running in local Server or building next app it responds ---> **res.json() is not a function**, I have also tried JSON.stringyfy() method but didn't work ***

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  connectDB();
  const res = await Product.find({product_type: 'mobile'});
  const data = await res.json();

  return {
    fallback: false,
    paths: data.map((mobile) => ({
      params: {
        mobId: mobile._id.toString(),
      },
    })),
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  connectDB();
  const res = await Product.findOne({_id: context.params.mobId});
  const data = await res.json();

  return {
    props: {
      mobData: data,
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: Have you tried logging `res` to see what it is?

Comment: Even though you are calling `await`, res will be a Promise

Comment: @Mikkel - that's not how `await` works, is it?

Comment: I have the feeling that `.find` and `.findOne` don't return a [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object at all

Comment: The value from an await expression is not a promise. Here's a line from the docs on this:
"When resumed, the value of the await expression is that of the fulfilled Promise."
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: is there a way i can fetch data from api routes , i tried normal async await fetch but it encounter problem in build time

Comment: Can you show us your `connectDB` function and `Product` model?